# How to mock specific lines in a function?

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to write test for my function but dont want to execute the certain statement s inside it .I am trying to mocking but failing .Any suggestion will be helpful.I am using pytest-mock for mocking.

```
def listDataSetZOWE():
"""To list out all datasets in system"""
try:

    process = Popen([zowe_path, 'zos-files','list','data-set','XYZ*'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    process.kill()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    stderr=e

return stderr
```

I dont want below two lines get excuted while testing

```
 process = Popen([zowe_path, 'zos-files','list','data-set','XYZ*'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

My test:

```
def test_listDataSetZOWE(mocker):
    mocker.patch("process = Popen([zowe_path, 'zos-files','list','data-set','MACK00*'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)","datasetobj")
    mocker.patch("stdout, stderr = process.communicate()","stderr")
    zowe.listDataSetZOWE()
```

Its failing with below error:

```
 TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: "process = Popen([zowe_path, 'zos-files','list','data-set','MACK00*'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)"
```

Comment: just patch `subprocess.Popen` maybe?

Comment: In the worst case you could extract those lines into a private function that returns your (stdout, stderr) tuple. Then you could mock the new function instead. Or you could mock Popen.

Comment: @ThatAnnoyingDude Not working.Same error.